# Does deleting the default value of function parameter still keep binary compatibility?

Tags: c++, binary-compatibility

I'm now debugging code but need to keep binary compatibility. There now is a modification about the default value of function parameter.

```
void functionName(const type parameter = class::A::getValue());
```

Now I want to just change it like this :

```
void functionName(const type parameter);
```

Is it still binary compatibility?

Comment: Probably (since the default argument is generated by the caller, so shouldn't affect how the function is called), but it depends on the ABI.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thank you Mike! So it's not to change function's signature since it doesn't affect how function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters don't change the type of a function. gcc 4.9.1 compiles this code without warnings:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static void f (int x) {
  cout << x << endl ;
}
static void g() ;

int main() {
  f (99) ;
  g() ;
  return 0 ;
}

static void f (int x = 101) ;

static void g() {
  f() ;
}
```

Re-declaring `f` to take a default parameter value is allowed here, which means that its linkage is unchanged. So you'll be OK.

Comment: Redeclaring is not redefining. You cannot redefine a function.

Comment: @rubenvb: Thank you for that! I have edited my answer accordingly.